# Bootstrap Collapse Menu - How Can I modify the Text in the <li> Items?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 with a nav bar.  The nav bar will collapse
when the screen size is small.

When the screen size is large I want all of the menu items to fit within the width of the window, so I use a <br> tag to force them to use two lines.

When the screen size is small and the collapse menu is clicked, the menu items still appear on two lines because of the <br> tags I inserted.
But I would prefer the menu items appear on one line.

How can I do this?  Is it possible to change the "data-target" attribute
in the button tag so that data-target points to another set of <li> elements that do not have <br> elements?

I suppose another way would be to use JavaScript to change the "innerHTML" property of the <li> elements when the screen size is small.

Thanks for your help!

```
.navbar-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
}

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button> 
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
</div>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home<a></li>
    <li><a href="#">White<br />Teas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Green<br />Teas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Oolong<br />Teas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Black<br />Teas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Herbal<br />Teas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blooming<br />Teas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mate<br />Teas</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to take off your breaking tags, and put that into your CSS :

```
.navbar-nav li {
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-align:center;
    max-width:10%;
}
@media (max-width:768px){
    .navbar-nav li {
    max-width:100% !important;
}
}
```

So you'll work on the width of the li tags to make their text break or be aligned.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ayadi102/85vb9qdd/)